# NodeJs : save my "unhandledRejection" promises to a text file

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have a stupid problem...

I do not manage to save my "unhandledRejection" errors to a text file...

I'm using a NodeJs program with Winston to handle logs, and :

- I manage to display unhandledRejection errors on the screen with console.error(error)
- but I do NOT manage to save this content to a log file... When I use logger.info(error) it shows me the words :

> [object Promise]

[Error on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VjBa.png)

--> how can I catch properly those errors and save it into my logs ?

Thanks

EDIT : here is a code sample. Just put your logger config file in the "const logger = " part

```js
   

 "use strict";

    // Load external files
    const ethers = require("ethers");

    // logging config
    const logger = require("put here your logger file config");

    process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
        console.log("")
        logger.error('----- ERROR : more details below -----')
        logger.info('----- Unhandled Rejection at -----')
        logger.info(promise)
        logger.info('----- Reason -----')
        logger.info(reason)
        console.log("")
    })

    const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("wss://ws-matic-mainnet.chainstacklabs.com");

    function startSniper() {
        provider._websocket.on("open", async () => {
            launch_nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(dummy);
        });

    };
      

    // START the bot
    startSniper();
```

EDIT 2 : new snippet trying to apply your impossible fix... or am I wrong ??

```js
// TRYING TO APPLY YOUR SOLUTION

 "use strict";

 // Load external files
 const ethers = require("ethers");

 // logging config
 const logger = require("put here your logger file config");

 process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.log("")
    logger.error('----- ERROR : more details below -----')
    logger.info('----- Unhandled Rejection at -----')
    const resolvedPromise = await promise // this solution does not work ! Error : 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.
    logger.info(resolvedPromise)
    logger.info('----- Reason -----')
    logger.info(reason)
    console.log("")
 })

 const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider("wss://ws-matic-mainnet.chainstacklabs.com");

 async function startSniper() {
     provider._websocket.on("open", async () => {
         launch_nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(dummy);
     });

 };
   

 // START the bot
 startSniper();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Promise but want to get the value from it, you will need to wait for the promise to resolve or reject. In this case it's the rejection specifically that is an issue. There are two ways to handle this in JavaScript.

```js
const promise = fetchSomeData()
const promise2 = fetchSomeOtherData()
let data, data2

// use await to process promise, catch any errors
try {
  data = await promise
} catch (error) {
  logger.info(`Promise rejected - could not fetch data with error ${error}`)
}

//use then() to process promise, handle any errors
promise2.then(
  (value) => { data2 = value },
  (reason) => { logger.info(`Promise rejected - could not fetch data with reason ${reason}`) }
}

await promise2
```

If your logger is showing a promise object it means that the promise has not resolved or rejected yet and so you need some code that will delay program execution until either of those things happens.

---

Looking at the code sample, try changing this and see whether that works

```js
const resolvedPromise = await promise
logger.info(resolvedPromise)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but still, I do not manage to make it work... Even with try/catch... even after trying to wait 1s before using logger.info with no luck... I'm becoming crazy.

Comment: @TsarBuig can you edit a minimum reproducible example into your question? If I can see the code maybe I can find the bug

Comment: here you go bro, I added some code :) thanks a lot

Comment: @TsarBuig check the edited-in part of the answer

Comment: If I do that, I have this error : "'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules."

Comment: @TsarBuig make the function that this statement sits in `async` as well (and the function around that as well, if necessary)

Comment: You might benefit from reading up on asynchronous javascript in general

Comment: I promise you bro, I understand quite well how it works because my software uses asynchronous functions all the time, but your solution does not work. VsCode just underline it as a fault : https://imgur.com/a/1ycxgCD   . Would it be possible that you edit my code snippet with an example supposed to work ? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @TsarBuig Given that this entire issue is due to issues around how you are using asynchronous code, I'd like to kindly suggest that you might not understand it as well as you think. I've edited the snippet - give it a try now.

Comment: Bro, once again, thanks again for your time. But I'm sorry, your solution is not applicable ! We're talking about unhandledRejection here, of course I know that your new snippet would work in any other case, but how to use it for unhandledRejection ?

I've edited my original message trying to apply what you say, and you'll see it's impossible